# Javascript IE8 not passing 'this' in attachEvent

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, internet-explorer-8, dom-events

Here is a script that looks at the links that exist on a page and binds a `mousedown` event listener to each link.  When a `mousedown` event is triggered it calls a function that creates an alert with the link's href.  In IE9+, this works fine, but in IE8, this is undefined.

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="http://www.example.com">test</a>
<script>
var c=function(){alert(this.href)};
var a=document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var b=0; b<a.length; b++) {
    if (a[b].addEventListener) {
        a[b].addEventListener("mousedown",c,false);
    } else {
        a[b].attachEvent("onmousedown",c);
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried adding `this` and `this.href` as arguments to the function, but it doesn't look like those functions accept arguments.  Anyone know how I would get this to work?

Comment: Most people would use JQuery indeed like `$("a").on("mousedown",c)` but you probably looking for raw JavaScript solution... Would [closure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) work for your case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var c = function (e) {
    e = e || event; // if e is not available, use global event object
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement; // some browsers use target to refer to event target, and some srcElement
    alert(target.href);
};
```

I think IE8 uses a global event object, instead of sending parameter in callback function.

Comment: `e.target`/`e.srcElement` is not necessarily the same element as *this* within the listener.

Comment: @Rob: sorry not clear, but the target will contain href, wouldnt it ?

Comment: @coder—within the listener, *this* will be the element that has the listener, the *event.target* or *event.srcElement* is the element that initiated the event. So where the element with the listener has child elements, *this* may not be the same as *event.target*. E.g., if the listener is on the A element and it has a child span element, then for a click on the span *this* will reference the A element and *event.target* / *event.srcElement* will reference the span.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, in the IE event model, listeners attached using *attachEvent* do not have their *this* set to the calling element so it defaults to *window* (i.e. the global object).

So instead of:

```
  a[b].attachEvent("onmousedown",c);
```

you can ensure *this* is set to the element using:

```
  a[b].attachEvent("onmousedown",(function(fn, el) {
    return function() {fn.call(el, event)};
  }(c, a[b]));
```

Look for examples of "addEvent" function, there are many around that fix this issue.